# Interaction DataTriggers Not Working

Tags: wpf, interaction

I have set up a pretty straightforward prototype. Using Blend 4, I set up some simple sample data source called 'Quote' that has Collection with two properties P1 and P2. P1 is a 4-digit number, P2 is a string.  There are two other simple properties, SecurityType and Price. These two properties are under Quote.

I am using the i:Interaction.Triggers and DataTriggers with GoToStateAction.  These work fine if I run it in a Silverlight project. In WPF, the DataTriggers do not work.
AM I missing something? NO compile or runtime errors in WPF.  IF I use WPF DataTriggers in the DataTemplate I defined, it works fine, but I need XAML that is cross-compatible with SL and WPF.

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 

xmlns:SampleData="clr-namespace:Expression.Blend.SampleData.Quote" 

mc:Ignorable="d"    
Width="640" Height="480">

<Window.Resources>

<SampleData:Quote x:Key="Quote" d:IsDataSource="True"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="FieldListBaseItemTemplate" >
<Grid x:Name="Fields" Height="25" Background="Gray" Tag="Yes">

     <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
         <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
     </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding P2}" Value="ATT">
            <ei:GoToStateAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Fields}" StateName="SimpleFieldState"  />
        </ei:DataTrigger>
        <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding P2}" Value="HL" >
            <ei:GoToStateAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Fields}" StateName="OtherFieldState"  />
        </ei:DataTrigger>
        <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding P2}" Value="Ford" >
            <ei:GoToStateAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Fields}" StateName="OtherFieldState"  />
        </ei:DataTrigger>

    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <!--            
        <ei:DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding P2}" Value="ATT" TrueState="SimpleFieldState" FalseState="None" />
        <ei:DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding P2}" Value="Ford" TrueState="OtherFieldState" FalseState="None"/>
        <ei:DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding P2}" Value="HL" TrueState="OtherFieldState" FalseState="None"/>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ei:DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding P2}" Value="ATT" TrueState="SimpleFieldState" FalseState="None"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors> 
-->


    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FieldsListStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="None"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="SimpleFieldState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="FieldLabel">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="FieldValue">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" Storyboard.TargetName="FieldLabel">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="30-Day Yield"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" Storyboard.TargetName="FieldValue">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="23.34"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="OtherFieldState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="FieldLabel">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="FieldValue">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" Storyboard.TargetName="FieldLabel">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Close Price"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" Storyboard.TargetName="FieldValue">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" >
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Binding ElementName="LayoutRoot" Path="DataContext.SecurityType" FallbackValue="Failed to Bind" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="125"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="125"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,-1,0,1" Width="85" Background="Black">
        <TextBlock x:Name="FieldLabel" Foreground="White"/>
    </Border>
    <Border x:Name="border" Grid.Column="1" Width="Auto" Background="Black" >
        <TextBlock x:Name="FieldValue" Foreground="White"  />
    </Border>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>



</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Quote}}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition /><RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="T" Text="{Binding SecurityType}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="14" Width="54" Margin="0" LineHeight="14" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"/>

    <ListBox MaxHeight="355" Background="AntiqueWhite" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,1,0" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource FieldListBaseItemTemplate}"/>
</Grid>

</Window>
```